# How to find my drives on Xubuntu 10 live mode

Tags: linux, windows-xp, xubuntu

I loaded `Xubuntu 10` from USB because I want to repair my `boot.ini` file(*Windows XP*).

But I can't see my Hard drive in the file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should occur in `/media` and there in some subdirectory which should be the UUID